# Current topology does not support session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, async-await

[image]

Hi,

I am getting error "**Current topology does not support session**"
Plese refer attached image..

and code as

```
async function insertBooking(parking, aFunction) {
    const session = await BookingSchema.startSession().catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    try {
        session.startTransaction();
        let booking = new BookingSchema(parking)
        mongoose.startSession();
        booking.save(function (err, booking) {
            if (booking) {
               //code to be run
            }


        })
        await session.commitTransaction().catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
        session.endSession()
    } catch (error) {
        await session.abortTransaction().catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
        session.endSession();
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Above code completely work on local system.
but erro occure on cloud server (Digital ocean) 
Please let me know if another information needed.

Comment: Have you checked the mongodb version on server? it must be >=4.0

Comment: After lots of trial i am able to change verison of mongodb .. First i removed old mongodb and install new version..
Now the above code working fine..

** Please let me know how to check mongodb version.. **

Comment: Run `mongod` to know the version.

Comment: try `> db.runCommand({buildInfo: 1})` to get the version in the cloud mongodb console.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you haven't installed `MongoDB 4.0` on your cloud server which supports transactions.

Transaction works only with >= MongoDB v4.0

Comment: Im facing the same issue, in Windows OS, but it works great in Ubuntu.  Anything to add on in Windows ????

Comment: with the fresh `image : mongo:4` I am getting the same error