# MongoDB : Current Topology does not support session

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I am learning MEAN Stack development. I am trying to execute a transaction.
Steps I followed :

1. I start the mongod.exe with flag set to --replSet rs0.
2. Then I start the Mongo Shell.
   Then I write following code.

```
let session: ClientSession | undefined;
    try {
        const data = req.body;
        console.log(data);
        const movie = new Movie({ name: data['name'], cast: data['cast'] });
        const conn = await db.connect()
        session = await conn.startSession()
        session.withTransaction(async () => {
            const doc = await movie.save({ session: session, validateBeforeSave: true });
            SuccessResponse(res);
            res.json(doc);
        })
        await session.commitTransaction()
        session.endSession();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        await log(err)
        if (session) {
            //session.abortTransaction();
            session.endSession()
        }
        ServerError(res);
        res.end();
    }
```

But I got follwoing error

```
MongoError: Current topology does not support sessions
```

Any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Current topology does not support session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928508/current-topology-does-not-support-session)

Comment: No. I am already using version 4.2.x

Comment: can you provide `rs.status()` results?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like if your connection was on a hold (eg. hitting a break point), `MongoError: Current topology does not support sessions` gets thrown even though `Current topology..` part does not have nothing to do with it. Maybe `Session connection timed out. Try again` would be more appropriate.

So, if you are sure your setup should support sessions, just try again.